# PHP - htaccess - output_buffering

Tags: php, .htaccess, output-buffering

I have the following code in an htaccess file in my application root to turn output buffering on.

```
php_value output_buffering On
php_value output_handler mb_output_handler
```

On some servers it causes a 500 internal error, on others it works fine. Does anyone know why it sometimes causes an error. Is there a different way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are those servers that return errors running a PHP version prior to 4.0.4?

Comment: No, they are all 5.2 or above.

Comment: Hey i was facing redirect issues i just add the above 2 line in .htaccess file and added ob_start() and flush() methods in my file Its works like a charm thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this syntax only [if PHP is running as an Apache module.](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

The 500 errors probably come up on servers where this is not the case.

For total certainty, look into the server's `error.log` file for a detailed error message.

Comment: Even if we take that the server does not run PHP as Apache module, **Why would it throw a 500 error?** Isn't the contents of the .htaccess file merely ignored?

Comment: @Pacerier no, Apache always throws a 500 error when it encounters an unknown command.

Answer (score 2):

Those directives work only if PHP is installed as a module. On other servers it will result in  500, since they will be invalid directives

Comment: Even if we take that the server does not run PHP as Apache module, Why would it throw a 500 error? Isn't the contents of the .htaccess file merely ignored?

Comment: No, contents are evaluated as directives, and if PHP module is not there, Apache would not know how to interpret "php_value" directive, so it will fail with 500

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but i think the error is caused by the first line.

Use php_flag for On/Off True/False switches, like this:

```
php_flag output_buffering On
```