# Enabling output buffering through htaccess or php.ini is causing Error 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, output-buffering

Title basically says it all. I'm trying to enable output buffering on a hostgator server. When I do I get an error 500 on my .php pages. Other .html pages seem to work fine.

this is the code I'm using in the .htaccess:

```
php_value output_buffering On
```

I've read that this is caused when PHP isn't running as an Apache module. However, is there anything I can do to fix this or somehow enable output_buffering anyway?

thank you!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642097/php-htaccess-output-buffering) is the same

Comment: @Deadooshka flag it as a duplicate then.

Comment: I've seen that response already, but it doesn't really answer how to solve the issue.

Comment: Depends on the PHP Server installation. There are many alternatives. From .htaccess to single custom php.ini to recursive php.ini. Ask your hosting support.

You may use suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/www/folder in .htaccess and then drop a php.ini file inside that folder with the variables you want to customize.

Comment: If your PHP installation is as FastCGI instead of Apache Module that flags won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP_flag. This may not cause that error. If it doesn't work use apache. ;) Why do you need this function?

Anyway try this in a .htaccess file and have a look at the error log and post it.

```
php_flag output_buffering On
```

*Edit:* Ohh and before doing so disable it in the php.ini first.

Comment: php_flag gives me the same error. I need this because I'm having trouble using header commands in php. they give me a "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" error.