# Is there any possibility my Yii application can work on an output_buffering enabled host?

Tags: php, yii, shared-hosting, output-buffering

I am using a shared hosting service to host my application which has `output_buffering` enabled on it. It seems Yii needs `output_buffering` disabled as a prerequisite.

But as I'm using a shared host, I can't disable it. 
So what should I do to make my Yii application work on the same host?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: You can always change host

Comment: @Daenarys: I haven't tried any code yet as I have no idea what I should try.

Comment: Changing host is the last option @Justinas. I just want to check if it is possible on the same host.

Comment: To check if it's possible, upload basic Yii application to host.

Comment: Already uploaded and its not working. That's the reason I'm here to find any workaround @Justinas

Comment: You may give a try to [ini-set function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ini-set.php) or work with .htaccess files if you're allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using .htcaccess if PHP is running as an Apache module.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
  php_admin_flag output_buffering Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
  php_admin_flag output_buffering Off
</IfModule>
```

Check this answer
[PHP - htaccess - output_buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642097/php-htaccess-output-buffering)

Comment: Unfortunately PHP is not running as an Apache module, so it is throwing 500 error. :(

Comment: @Satyajit are you getting any error messages without try to turn off the output buffer and which version of YII are you using